# How to map several json fields to a single java map?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

How to map this JSON to this Java object where the `habits` Map will have the keys `HabitName.FITNESS` and `HabitName.MATHEMATICS` with the corresponding values? Constructor, getters and setters are omitted to readability.

```
{
  "habits": {
    "fitness": {
      "duration": "1 week",
      "score": "2.1"
    },
    "mathematics": {
      "duration": "2 weeks",
      "score": "2.4"
    }
  }
}
```

```
public class IncomingJson {
  Map<HabitName, HabitDesc> habits;

  public enum HabitName {
    @JsonProperty("fitness") FITNESS,
    @JsonProperty("mathematics") MATHEMATICS
  }
  
  public static class HabitDesc {
    String duration;
    String score;
  }
}
```

At runtime I get the following Exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "fitness" (class IncomingJson), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "habits")
```

Comment: Use `FITNESS` means capital form as key in Json

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks not necessary, I can use @JsonProperty("fitness") on Enum value.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? You already seem to have the right class structure

Comment: @Joni I have ```com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "fitness" (class IncomingJson), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "habits") 
```

Comment: Please double check the format of the JSON you're parsing. It sounds like the JSON object you get has "fitness" field on the top level, instead of "habits"

Comment: Please update the question with your json deserialization code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was close. You can deserialize this JSON into the following Java class easily.

```
{
    "root" : {
        "habits": {
            "fitness": {
                "duration": "1 week",
                "score": "2.1"
            },
            "mathematics": {
                "duration": "2 weeks",
                "score": "2.4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@JsonRootName("root")
publi class Habits {
    private final Map<HabitName, HabitDesc> habits = new HashMap<>();
    public enum HabitName {
        @JsonProperty("fitness") FITNESS,
        @JsonProperty("mathematics") MATHEMATICS
    }
    @Getter
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static class HabitDesc {
        @JsonProperty("duration") private final String duration;
        @JsonProperty("score") private final String score;
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: The above class relies on `lombok.anyconstructor.addconstructorproperties=true` in the *lombok.config* file in the same package as *Habits.class*.

So your deserialization code will look like this

```
var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
Habits = objectMapper.readValue(JSON_STRING, Habits.class);
```